# RegEx all URLs that do NOT contain a string

Tags: regex, google-analytics, goal-tracking

I seem to be having a bit of a brain fart atm. I've got Google counting my transitions correctly but I'm getting false positives.

This is the current goal RegEx which works great.

```
^/click/[0-9]+\.html\?.*
```

But I also want it the RegEx to NOT county anything that has `&confirm=1` I'm quite stuck as to how to do that in the RegEx, I thought I might be able to use `[^(?:&confirm=1)]` but I don't think that's valid.

Comment: Note that `[]` specifies a character class, and `^` negates the class, so `[^(?:&confirm=1)]` is actually looking for any character which is not one of `(?:&confirm=1)`.

Comment: argh of course! damn i knew this!

Answer (score 5):

Use "exclude", not "include" filter option

Comment: Tried to upvote this answer now, apparently I already did so 2 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^/click/[0-9]+\.html\?(?!.*\bconfirm=1).*
```

I changed it slightly so it will still exclude if `confirm=1` is the first param (preceded by the `?` rather than `&`)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't... I've tried doing this before, what I found was that you used to be able to do this with `negative lookahead` (see Rubens), but Google Analytics stopped supporting this at some point (source: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/3YnwXM0WYxE).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm a little late.

What about just writing :

```
[^(&confirm=1)]
```

?

Comment: That will match all characters which are not in the set `()&=confirm1`